# BehaviorRelayでshare(replay: 1)をする意味

Tags: swift, ios, rx-swift

RxSwiftのBehaviorRelayを使って `share(replay: 1)` しているコードを見かけることがあります。

```
let relay = RxCocoa.BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
var observable: RxSwift.Observable<String> {
    return relay
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .share(replay: 1)
        // ↑ここ
}
```

BehaviorRelayはsubscribe時に現在値を返すと思うのですが、 `share(replay: 1)` を書く意味って何なのでしょうか？

**参考**
[【RxSwift】BehaviorRelayとPublishRelayについてまとめてみた](https://egg-is-world.com/2018/08/11/rxswift-behaviorrelay-publishrelay/)

Comment: `.share(replay:1)` の前にHot-Cold変換するようなオペレータが挟まった時のことを懸念して、おまじない的につけてるんでしょうか。。。 `observeOn` はHot-Cold変換しないと思いますが。

Answer (score 1):

(一個人の経験ですが、)ここ数年ずっとRx使っているプロジェクトにいますが、BehaviorRelayに.share(replay: 1)を付けているコードは見たことありませんね

.share(replay:1)は(基本的に)hot変換するために使う物ですが、そもそも直前のBehaviorRelayがhotなので意味ないです。。。

ただコメントにもある通り、もし

```swift
var observable: RxSwift.Observable<String> {
    return relay
        .map { $0.uppercased() }
        .share(replay: 1)
```

みたいに直前にcoldに変換するオペレーターがついていたら、例え1回しか購読しないとしても、今後のことを考えると意味あると思います！